# In a Diffusion Model what do I need to implement to compute the KL divergence between P and Q?

Tags: diffusion-models

Based on the original DDPM paper, $ P_\theta(X) $ is the distribution where we draw noise from and remove it from $ X_T $ to get an image; $ Q(X) $ is the distribution where we draw noise from and add it to get $ X_t $, a noisy image.

The mean and variance of $ Q $ are defined as fixed parameters, but the mean and variance of $ P_\theta $ are unknown and are derived from the neural network output.

I struggle to understand how to derive the mean and variance of $ P $ from the NN output. This is needed to compute the $ \mathcal{D}_\mathrm{KL}(P || Q) $.